# JPA SortedSet is not being resorted after persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with the following field:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, targetEntity = Comment.class)
@JoinTable(name = "program_to_comment")
@OrderBy("position")
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
```

but I have the problem that whenever I persist it using:

```
Program p = entityManager.persist(entity);
```

the field comes with the objects sorted as it was sorted in the `entity` object.

Suppose the `entity` object is configured as following: `Program(comments:[Comment(position:15), Comment(position:10)], ...)`, persisting the entity (`entityManager.persist`), it will store both comments and the program entity itself to the database. But the resulted entity from the persist method invocation is an object as follows: `Program(comments:[Comment(position:15), Comment(position:10)], ...)`, in the same order gave to the persist method.

From my point of view at this point the resulted entity should present the values following the specified @OrderBy rule, or am I missing something?

Additional information:

- JPA2
- Hibernate 4.2.0.Final

Comment: If you take the approach of using an [`@OrderColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) annotation instead, and so not putting the position in the `Comment` object, then you can control the order of the comments by controlling their position in the list. This should then stay consistent between application and database. I'm not sure if this really helps, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrderBy simply add an order by clause to the query used to load the comments of a program. Nothing more. The rest is under your responsibility. So if you want the comments sorted by position when adding comments and persisting them, you have to take care of this by yourself.

I have personally never found this annotation to be really useful. I have also found it not to work in every case, particularly when using a query to fetch programs with their comments, with an order by clause already present in the query. I generally prefer not to use theis annotation, and provide a `getSortedComments()` method which returns a sorted set or list of comments, using a comparator.

Comment: The useless of it was exactly my perception, I found a solution by using [@Sort](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted) but it is Hibernate specific. I just implementated `java.util.Comparable` and annotated the field with `@Sort(SortType.NATURAL)`.